# unable to create record center as a subsite under record center site collection using full control permissions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, records-center

**I am unable to create a subsite using record center template under "Record center site collection". Currently I have full control permissions. Does anyone know why? 
I can able to create a team site or other sites under that site collection but except "RC".**

If i add myself as site collection admin then there is no issue while creating it.

Comment: What oob permission level were you using when your attempts failed?

Answer (score 0):

This might be happen due to below reasons.

First login as site collection admin then do below process.

1. Internally, SharePoint manages a hidden list named "**TaxonomyHiddenList**". URL of the list is -  "**[sitecollectionURL]/lists/taxonomyhiddenlist**".
2. Generally, All authenticated users (everyone) has Read access to this list.
3. As a site collection administrator user, when I checked permissions of the list, I found none of user or group were having permissions to this list as you can see in below screenshot.

[image]

> **Resolution**:

The solution was simple once identified. We should assign read access to all authenticated users (Everyone) operating within the site collection. Or We can delete unique permissions.

For Details you refer [blog](http://blog.binaryrepublik.com/2017/03/users-with-full-control-permission-are.html#.W2PpH9IzaUl)

Comment: I already tried this solution and still there is no luck. We are getting "sorry you don't have access" error.

Comment: For this you need to login as site collection admin. This might me right solution for you because if you don't have access to texonomyhiddenlist then you can't create a sub site